# Замена switch-case

Tags: php, архитектура, антипаттерн

Имеется конструкция switch-case со множеством вариантов. Каким образом создать компонентно-ориентированный и легко масштабируемый архитектурный аналог?

Например:

```
<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

switch ($method) {
case 'GET':
  //Here Handle GET Request 
  getHandle();
  break;
case 'POST':
  //Here Handle POST Request
  postHandle();
  break;
case 'DELETE':
  //Here Handle DELETE Request 
  deleteHandle();
  break;
case 'PUT':
  //Here Handle PUT Request 
  putHandle();
  break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это работает не только в php. Для каждой большой конструкции switch-case уместно создавать ассоциативный массив из обработчиков. Переменная, хранящая "состояние", подставляется в ключ массива и вызывается соответствующий обработчик.

Получаем переменную, храняющую "состояние"

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

Пишем обработчики

```
function getHandle(){
    echo "get запрос";
}

function postHandle(){
    echo "post запрос";
}

function putHandle(){
    echo "put запрос";
}

function deleteHandle(){
    echo "delete запрос";
}
```

Ассоциативный массив из ссылок на обработчики. Подробнее о [переменных функций](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.variable-functions.php).

```
$httpArr = array(
    'GET' => 'getHandle',
    'POST' => 'postHandle',
    'PUT' => 'putHandle',
    'DELETE' => 'deleteHandle'
    );
```

Вызов нужного обработчика

```
$httpArr[$method]();
```

В js можно создать ссылку на функцию в виде переменной. Затем поместить переменную в массив. И вызывать функцию прямо из массива. Тут такой же принцип.
Грубо говоря, $httpArr - это массив функций.

P.S. Тестил для php версии 7.

Comment: оказывается это называется табличный метод макконнела=) Кто-то может назвать это упрощением паттерна фабрика. Т.к. в некоторых языках нет возможности простого создания массива обьектов разных классов и ссылок на функции. В любом случае для php и js это самый элегантный способ на мой взгляд.

Comment: Случайно прочел удаленный почти год назад ваш ответ на Мете на [этот вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4770/232). Реально здорово написано (недаром удалили...)